# Validation in Spring REST + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, validation, rest

today I have short question
I have my backend project in Spring REST api, and frontend page using HTML5 CSS3 and jQuery. I want to validate the data that comes from user.

Which approach is better - to validate in the frontend side by using jQuery/JavaScript - or validate it on serverside in controller etc?

Comment: Validate on both sides.

Comment: The server-side validation is always more secure. So no matter what happens to javascript, you will always have a valid data, when form is submitted. On the other hand, validation on the client is more responsive and eye-pleasing to the user. Whichever you need - is entirely your own preference :) You can do both, if you have time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should do both. Conventionally front end validation is thought of as a convenience service to the user. Validation on the back end is for your sake.